# What is the best practice of a Dapp development mixed with Python/Django?

Tags: dapps, web3.py, python, django

I've written and tested the Smart Contracts in Truffle, and now want to develop a front-end and a small back-end for my Dapp. So far, I preferred MVP frameworks, particularly Django. Therefore, what is the best practice of setting up a small back-end on Python with MongoDB (to store texts and images) by using Django and linking it to the Ethereum network? 
I'm having a hard time to building the architecture of how everything will be glued together...

Comment: You can integrate web3.py lib https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: If you have other than Python and Django?

Answer (score 0):

To start with Ethereum and Python development, Ethereum documentation "Python" page is a good place to start.

- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/python/

It will also contains references to frameworks like Web3.py and ApeWorX that allow EVM chain integration with Django.